# In YugabyteDB YSQL, how can we track the number of active connections on each server?

Tags: database, server, tracking, distributed-database, yugabytedb

How can we track the active connections to a yb-tserver at a given time, and what client IP address the connection is originating from? Mostly need this for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You can see active YSQL connections in location `http://<any-tserver-ip>:13000/rpcz` of any yb-tserver ip.

It will return a json response (example below):

```
{
    "connections": [
        {
            "db_oid": 12457,
            "db_name": "yugabyte",
            "query": "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_tablets_11(id bigserial primary key) SPLIT (INTO 150 TABLETS);",
            "application_name": "",
            "process_start_time": "2020-02-20 14:09:57.272725+00",
            "transaction_start_time": "2020-02-20 14:10:12.780273+00",
            "query_start_time": "2020-02-20 14:10:12.780273+00",
            "application_name": "",
            "backend_type": "client backend",
            "backend_status": "active",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": "44434"
        },
        {
            "application_name": "",
            "process_start_time": "2020-02-20 13:39:58.133322+00",
            "application_name": "",
            "backend_type": "checkpointer",
            "backend_status": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

You can view all active requests (RPCs) on each tserver in `:9000/utilz`:

[image]